What is meant by $\int_{a}^{b}|\left \{ f_1(x),f_2(x),f_3(x),\dots,f_n(x) \right \}|\mathrm{d}x$?
What is meant by $\int_{a}^{b}|\left \{ f_1(x),f_2(x),f_3(x),\dots,f_n(x) \right \}|\mathrm{d}x$?
Like:
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\bigg|\left \{\left \lfloor \sin(x) \right \rfloor,\left \lfloor \cos(x) \right \rfloor,\left \lfloor \tan(x) \right \rfloor,\left \lfloor \cot(x) \right \rfloor\right \}\bigg|\mathrm{d}x$$
The result of which is $\frac{11}{2}\pi$.
Source: MIT Integration Bee, $2024$, Quarterfinal $\text{#}3$, Problem $\text{#}1$.

I know that
$\left \lfloor u \right \rfloor$ is the floor function, which returns the greatest integer that is less than or equal to $u$.
$\left \lceil u \right \rceil$ is the ceiling function, which returns the least integer that is greater than or equal to $u$. (It is not appearing in the problem).
$|u|$ is the absolute value, which returns $u$ if $u \ge 0$, and returns $-u$ when $u < 0$.
$\left \{ u \right \}$ is the fractional part of $u$, which returns $u-\left \lfloor u \right \rfloor$.

If the question was
$\int_{a}^{b}|\mathrm{max}\left( \left \{ f_1(x)\right \},\left \{f_2(x)\right \},\left \{f_3(x)\right \},\dots,\left \{f_n(x) \right \}\right)|\mathrm{d}x$
or
$\int_{a}^{b}|\mathrm{min}\left( \left \{ f_1(x)\right \},\left \{f_2(x)\right \},\left \{f_3(x)\right \},\dots,\left \{f_n(x) \right \}\right)|\mathrm{d}x$
then it is fine.

I am not asking you to show the solution of this integral, but asking about the used notation. Is it known? Or did they miss something like $\mathrm{max}(.,.,.,.)$ or $\mathrm{min}(.,.,.,.)$?

Your help would be appreciated. THANKS!

I'm not certain, but it looks like $|\cdot|$ may denote the cardinality of the relevant set.

Define the set $S(x) = \{f_1(x) ,f_2(x), f_3(x), f_4(x)\}$ , where $$f_1(x) = \lfloor\sin{x}\rfloor,\, f_2(x) = \lfloor\cos{x}\rfloor, \, f_3(x) = \lfloor\tan{x}\rfloor ,\, f_4(x) = \lfloor\cot{x}\rfloor. $$
The integral is asking $\int_{0}^{2\pi} |S(x)| dx$, where $|\cdot|$ denotes cardinality of the set $S(x)$.

... The set here consists of four functions, though. Would the integral you propose not just be $8\pi$, as opposed to $11\pi/2$?

@PrincessEev For any given value of $x$, this set consists of at most four integers.  It's possibly less than four due to repetitions.  (If it were $|{f_1, f_2, f_3, f_4}|$ then it would be "four functions")

Oh I see now, it's not a static object, the set $S$ also depends on $x$, so sometimes there may be $3$ or fewer values.

A set by definition can only have unique elements in it.  @PrincessEev So to solve this integral it would be wise to draw the curves and see how many distinct elements the set $S$ will have. I can add a detailed solution, but I don't want to spoil the fun for OP.

Yeah, don't worry, I get it now. Thanks though. I can't imagine solving this in a handful of minutes though lol

@Sam If the cardinality is $4$, $\int=8\pi$. If the cardinality is $3$, $\int=6\pi$. If the cardinality is $2$, $\int=4\pi$. If the cardinality is $1$, $\int=2\pi$. If the cardinality is $0$, $\int=0$. Can the cardinality of a set be a value that is not an integer?

It will always be an integer, but not the same integer through the interval of integration. For instance, $\lfloor \sin x \rfloor = \lfloor \cos x \rfloor = \lfloor \tan x \rfloor = 0$, $\lfloor \cot x \rfloor \ge 1$ for $x<\frac{\pi}{4}$. So the cardinality of the set would be $2$ for $x<\frac{\pi}{4}$. @Hussain-Alqatari

@Sam Thanks for your help.
